# 400. That’s an error.Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. Error in redirect URI in Google social login

Tags: java, spring, security

I am authenticating my app with google social login with Spring Security, while redirecting to Google, I got error in redirect URI.

My complete URL in the browser is:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=99073275104-4vn6mdqpunuf4dvcaakdtqd7lmf1hm1n.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fspring-security-social-login-example%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%3Bjsessionid%3DF48F03434963DFC1A292AE6370541348&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo%23email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ftasks+https%3A%2F%2Fwww-opensocial.googleusercontent.com%2Fapi%2Fpeople+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&state=7799de7d-e920-4bc6-9b07-d95e4eb8cf02

where redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fspring-security-social-login-example%2Fauth%2Fgoogle

I put http://localhost:8080/spring-security-social-login-example/auth/google in my Google console account but still showing the above error.

login.jsp:

```
<div class="span3">
    <form name='GoogleSocialloginForm' action="<c:url value='/auth/google' />" method='POST'>
        <img src="../images/gmail2.png" alt="">
        <button type="submit">
            <i>Sign In with Google</i>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

In the above jsp page, the redirection is going on to /auth/google. So I have appended the same in the redirection URL. Kindly suggest what'ss wrong in the redirect URL.

Comment: the ref. article I am implementing: https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecuritySocialLoginExample

Comment: After successful login the following controller will be called-

  @RequestMapping(value = {"/userpage"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring security social login Hello World");
        model.addObject("user", getUser());
        model.setViewName("user");
        return model;
    }

Comment: Hi anyone have idea pls.